# Can I cache click event on any website that does not belong to me

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, jquery-events, mashup

I am trying to append a script to any web site, using for example Chrome extensions. When the extension is on, the JavaScript would listen to the `mouseenter` event but not click event (because it would usually make the page jump to an other page)

My question is: can I cache the all the click events on page when my extension is on and recover them when off? Like:

```
//on 
for node in document
  old-click = node.click
  node.click = null
  node.addEventListener 'off', (e)->
    node.click = old-click
```

Or can I add a mask to the page that can stop click event to bubble but allow the `mousemove` event to bubble to the below element (only one but not bubble to all elements below)?

```
//click event 
$(document).on 'click', '*', (event)->
  event.stopPropagation()

$(document).on 'mousemove', '*', (event)->
  //event.bubbleToNextBelowElement
```

Comment: you are missing parenthesis right after on and should be closed that parentheses.

Comment: Thank you!! I am used to write coffeescript, so ...